# How to send APNS from inside my app

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Instead of having a remote server send APNS payloads, I want my app to, because they are just single timer based APNS payloads. Is this possible? I really don't want to have to create a whole web server just to send them for something this simple. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) Apple documentation page will help.

Answer (score 1):

search for local push notifications, there should be plenty resources available and yes you don't need webserver for this